# IDE static analysis for dynamically instantiated classes

Tags: php, oop, static-analysis

I'm creating a class from variables (in a controlled environment) like this:

```
$controller = new $controllerClassName();
```

But my IDE doesn't know what type of class is. So, I'd like to know if there is a way to identify the class (maybe I could create an interface).

This is what I want to do:

```
$controller = (InterfaceController) new $controllerClassName();
```

**Edit:** I'm using PhpStorm IDE

**Solution:**

As *yivi* suggests, I've used PHP-Doc annotations, so now it's **working**:

```
$controller = new $controllerClassName();
/** @var MyInterface $controller */
```

Note that "MyInterface" could be a class or an interface.

Also, I've tried to execute the following code, but it **didn't work**. It seems that the annotation must be in the same block of the variable:

```
/**
 * @param string $var1
 * @param string $var2
 * ...
 * @var MyInterface $controller
 */
function thisIsAFunction($var1, $var2, ...) {
    ...
    $controller = new $controllerClassName(); // <- Class still unknown
    ...
}
```

Comment: If the problem only concerns your IDE, you should definitely say which it is. I don't know PHP well, but with java+eclipse there are some annotations that help the IDE's static analysis and have no side effect in the compiled code. These annotations are specific to the IDE and would have no effect under another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify your ide, but in most competent PHP IDEs you can use [PHP-DOC annotations](https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/var.html) to specify type and help with static-analysis.

E.g.:

```
/** @var SomeClass $someClass */
$someClass->thisCouldBeAutoCompleted();
```

In your case, since you are instantiating your class dynamically for some reason, you probably should (as you said) use an interface which is implemented by the classes you are liable to instantiate, or an parent class for the family.

So maybe:

```
 $painter = new $painterImplementingClass();
 /** @var PaintInterface $painter $painter*/
 $painter->line($point1, $point2, $color);
 // auto-completion should work for Pencil, Pen, Brush and other
 // classes that implement PaintInterface
```

Or

```
 $vehicle = new $vehicleClass();
 /** @var AbstractVehicle $vehicle */
 $vehicle->accelerate($acceleration, $time);
 // auto-completion and static analysis should work for Car, Bicycle,
 // Boat and other classes that extend AbstractVehicle
```

Comment: Seems useful. I will try it lately

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you need to tune your IDE for a little.
Or to make it clear for your IDE you can use namespaces which will point to your `new $controllerClassName();`
You can read more about namespaces [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)